# xmirpc Error and cannot find main type in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Problem:  xmirpc and cannot find main type.

I am running Eclipse (4.9.0) and Java on a MacBook Pro under macOS Catalina 10.15.3.  I have a project that I had exported last week; a few days later I mistakenly removed (deleted) it while learning Git.  So, I imported it back in.
 If I mark the project name and press its drop-down arrow and select either new **configuration (8)** or new **configuration (5)** - I get the following error:
[image]

If I select either Run AS  Java Application, I receive the following error message:

[image]

I have a properly-formed Main class within the ProcessWid class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

in the Views section directly shown below:
[image]
If I select it, click right, select `Build Path  Add to Build Path`, I get the following error:

[image]
And ProcessWid.java is no longer under Views but has been moved to a Referenced Libraries folder:

[image]
I am now at a complete loss.  How do I get out of this mess?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have received no help on this question and I am tired of chasing errors/bugs in Eclipse, I have moved my project to IntelliJ.  My time is worth something.

IntelliJ is far better software.

Please consider this request closed.